# How can I express the term ( a < b ? 0 : 1 ) using only bitwise or arithmetic operators?

Tags: conditional-statements, bit-manipulation, integer-arithmetic

Assuming the variables a and b are 32 bit integers is there a way to compare the two and return 0 if a < b and 1 if a >= b without using a ternary nor a comparison operator?

Comment: When you tag your question as language-agnostic, you also need to say what you mean by 'bitwise or arithmetic operators'. "32 bit integers" is then not descriptive enough either.

Comment: Ah sorry. Well I guess I remove that tag better then.

Comment: Well, you could compare bit for bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it's not pretty.

The problem is, as mentioned, overflow. But you can work around it, like this:

```
return ((x - y) ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) ^ x))) >>> 31;
```

For the signed version, or

```
return ((~x & y) | ((~x | y) & (x - y))) >>> 31;
```

For the unsigned version.

The `>>>` there is an unsigned right shift, as in Java.

Use them with `x = b, y = a` to make them match your function.

You can find those (and others) in Hacker's Delight, under the name "comparison predicates".

Comment: Just when I had figured out a patch for @korhner's solution... Well, that one definitely works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First we take the difference of the two numbers. Then we are checking the sign using the fact that numbers are rappresented as complement of two.

```
int Compare(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a - b;
    int k = (c >> 31) & 1 ^ 1;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Note: use of 2's complement is not guaranteed.

Comment: Good point, but I think this is an interview question/assignment and the point is probably to assume we are using two's complement. I may be mistaken.

Comment: No, it's not at an interview question - I am just generally interested if there is a way to it this way. Unfortunately this method only works as long as the absolute difference between a and b is smaller than 0x80000000 - otherwise it seems the flag is cancelled out due to some overflow. Here are some a/b pairs that fail for me using this function:
-1515420139 : 1331972515;
-1639662173 : 1707213811; 
2103438625 : -128805261;

Comment: Yup, this method fails due to overflow for big ranges but that is the closest you can get without using comparison as far as I know.

Comment: @Rhymoid why not? The question isn't tagged C or anything like that. So it's abstract, and you can just define negative numbers to work any way you want.

Comment: @harold: I was only pointing out that "the fact that numbers are rappresented (sic) as complement of two" is not a fact in every situation.

Comment: I think by taking into account the 31st bit of a,b and c it might be possible to correct the overflow: the result is only wrong in two cases: (a >> 31) & 1) == 0, (b >> 31) & 1) == 1, (c >> 31) & 1) == 1 and (a >> 31) & 1) == 1, (b >> 31) & 1) == 0, (c >> 31) & 1) == 0. For all other combinations it's correct. So maybe by using the right bit operatior combination with these 3 bits it is possible to correct k.

Comment: kinda paradoxal, I am pretty sure the only way to correct the code for those overflow special cases is by using comparison operators/statements :)

Comment: This works for me - maybe this can even be shortened: 
int c = a - b;
int fa = ((a >> 31) & 1);
int fb = ((b >> 31) & 1);
int fc = ((c >> 31) & 1);
int k = (fc ^ 1)^(fa^fb)&((fb^fc)^1);

Comment: Thank you for your help - unfortunately Harold's answer works out of the box which is why I mark his as the solution.